# How to recover .git folder deletion?

Tags: windows, git, github, .git-folder

I accidentally deleted my .git folder, I would like to recover the .git folder, but I **permanently deleted it**.

Will I lose all my project's history?

I also tryed the [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120102/how-to-undo-the-deletion-of-my-git-folder) with no success.

**Notes**:

- It happened when I imported the code to the Eclipse IDE.
- I made many local changes without pushing them.
- I also using GitHub as a repo.
- Using Windows 10.

Comment: Normally the `.git` folder is a hidden folder. How did you delete it "accidentally" ?

Comment: It happened when I imported the code to the Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 2):

If you have pushed your changes to GitHub, then all your history is sitting in the repo on GitHub. You can clone the repo again.

If you have not pushed your changes to a remote repo, then the only place that those changes existed is in your local .git directory in your project directory, and those changes are now gone.

Comment: I actually made many local changes and don't wanna lose them.

Comment: First rule of computing: If it's not backed up, it's not important. It's lost if you don't have a backup.

Comment: You might also be able to use testdisk to recover the files.

Comment: Finally, you can simply reclone the repo into another folder and add the changes from the original clone to the new clone. You'll lose the local commit history but you'll at least have the code

Answer (score -3):

I had to re-clone the repository and paste the .git folder in the recently cloned project, into the project's folder.

So I only lost the local commits.